# How to derive the stability of time stepping schemes?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am an engineer and I am learning how to model the wave equation in Fenics. To obtain the fully discretised variational form in space and time, I have to implement a numerical method for evolution in time. I have been looking at Sympletic Euler, Crank Nicolson and Newmark Beta method.

In literature, it is reported that these methods are conditionally or unconditionally stable for certain values. Focussing on Newmark Beta method, it is reported that this method is unconditionally stable, if we choose the parameters 2β ≥ γ ≥ 1/2. Here beta and gamma are parameters in the Newmark scheme.

My question is: How do mathematicians derive this information about the stability of a method. Whether it is conditionally stable or unconditionally stable, and for which parameter values?

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction/ document/ papers? I am not researching this topic so I don't want to dive too deep into the associated mathematical research. I am just curious if there are plain derivations for this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm no expert in the field, but generally you calculate the condition number which is effectively the derivative of the process = the ratio of the change in the output to a small change in input.. If it is $\le 1$, the process is stable. If it not much larger than 1, then the process is only "quasi-stable". If it is very large, the process is unstable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number